# problems with spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, pdo

my problem is that on my page http://it-fix.nu/login.php i get the error

Warning: require_once(classes/input.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /customers/6/f/9/it-fix.nu/httpd.www/core/init.php on line 26 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'classes/input.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /customers/6/f/9/it-fix.nu/httpd.www/core/init.php on line 26

this is my core/init.php file

```
<?php session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'xxxxxx',
        'username' => 'xxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'db' => 'xxxxxxx'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register('myAutoloader');

function myAutoloader($className)
{
    $path = 'classes/';

    require_once $path.$className.'.php';
}

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

if (Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));

    if ($hashCheck->count()) {
        $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
        $user->login();
    }
}?>
```

i realize that the problem is upper and lower case sensitivity.

but if i change the file name from Input.php to input.php i am going to get the same error, but this time on http://it-fix.nu/register.php.

the two files are in the same folder.

Comment: Don't use relative path use absolute one.

Comment: i am pretty sure, it is not the path thats the problem, because as i said in the post, if i change the name of the file, it works in one place, but not the other. and vice versa.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? If the problem is case sensitivity, then you need to establish a rule how to deal with it. E.g., make everything lower case.